# How to create offsets from start in pandas, given length of segments and offsets in segment?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, cumsum

The title may not be the most informative.

I have the following working code I want to vectorize [no for loops] using native pandas.
Basically, it should return for each row its cumulative offset from `0`, given the length of each segment, and a relative offset within that segment.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"id":     [0, 1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  5,  6,  6,   7,   9],  # notice no 8
                   "length": [0, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 60, 60,  70,  90],
                   "offset": [0, 0,  1,  3,  4,  0,  7,  0,  0,  0,  1,   0,   0]})


result = np.zeros((len(df),))
current_abs = df.loc[0, "id"]
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if current_abs == df.loc[i, "id"]:
        result[i] = result[i - 1]
    else:
        current_abs = df.loc[i, "id"]
        result[i] = result[i - 1] + df.loc[i, "length"]

df["offset_from_start"] = result + df["offset"]

print(df)
```

> ```
>     id  length  offset  offset_from_start
> 0    0       0       0                  0
> 1    1      10       0                 10
> 2    2      20       1                 31
> 3    2      20       3                 33
> 4    2      20       4                 34
> 5    3      30       0                 60
> 6    3      30       7                 67
> 7    4      40       0                100
> 8    5      50       0                150
> 9    6      60       0                210
> 10   6      60       1                211
> 11   7      70       0                280
> 12   9      90       0                370
> ```

---

This seems like a fancy `cumsum` operation, but I don't know how to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try `mask` on the duplicated, then cumsum:

```
df['offset_from_start'] = (df['length'].mask(df.duplicated('id'),0)
                                       .cumsum() + df['offset']
                          )
```

Output:

```
    id  length  offset  offset_from_start
0    0       0       0                  0
1    1      10       0                 10
2    2      20       1                 31
3    2      20       3                 33
4    2      20       4                 34
5    3      30       0                 60
6    3      30       7                 67
7    4      40       0                100
8    5      50       0                150
9    6      60       0                210
10   6      60       1                211
11   7      70       0                280
12   9      90       0                370
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, same principle:

```
df['offset_from_start'] = (~df['id'].duplicated() * df['length']).cumsum() + df['offset']
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    id  length  offset  offset_from_start
0    0       0       0                  0
1    1      10       0                 10
2    2      20       1                 31
3    2      20       3                 33
4    2      20       4                 34
5    3      30       0                 60
6    3      30       7                 67
7    4      40       0                100
8    5      50       0                150
9    6      60       0                210
10   6      60       1                211
11   7      70       0                280
12   9      90       0                370
```

Below are the timings of each approach:

```
%timeit fun_dani_duplicated(df2)
647 µs ± 49.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit fun_quang_hoang(df3)
1.31 ms ± 264 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: can you explain why this method is faster? Will it also be faster for large dfs?

Comment: @Gulzar my guess is that there is some hidden complexity in the mask method. I cannot guarantee that is going to be faster for larger dfs.